# Why doesn't my view get rendered when my action is entered from a Ajax call?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I have a Ajax call that hit my controllers action 'SearchFromWithin' and I want to know why the view doesn't get displayed. I can enter the view and step through it, but the screen just stays as the same. It doesn't display the new view.

Here is my code

```js
var optionsFromWithin = {
     url: '/Home/SearchFromWithin',
     type: "get",
     data: { searchQuery: navbarInput.value, classDate: today, latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude, mapType: mapType }
};
            
$.ajax(optionsFromWithin).done(function (data) {
     // don't do anything here  
});
```

Here is the action in the controller. When I get to the return statement I can step into the "Search" view and step through it with no noticeable errors, but the page never changes from the one I was on when I made the Ajax call.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult SearchFromWithin(string searchQuery, DateTime classDate, string latitude, string longitude,
        string mapType, int page = 1)
    {
            // do a bunch of stuff here
            return View("Search", viewModel);
    }
```

Comment: Hi, try to use a partial view instead a view, so, change the return View to return PartialView("Search", viewModel), also remember that the PartialView only must have the html that is inside the body.

Comment: And please don't hard code your url's - use `url: '@Url.Action("SearchFromWithin", "Home")',`

Answer (score 4):

Could this be because you are not updating your page? Normally when you call ajax, don't you call a partial View, use its contents as html for a particular element[e.g DIV]?

```
return PartialView("viewName",Model);
```

and then when ajax call is done

```
$('#myDiv').html(data);
```

Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: I'm in a different controller, so the part that I want to replace doesn't even exist on the page. Does that matter?

Comment: What do you mean by different page? How did you want the page to change?

Answer (score 2):

Using ajax call you won't be able to navigate another page. We actually use Ajax to get the data from the Server and then update the client html with those data.

1. Use this code in the controller

   ```
   return PartialView("viewName",Model);
   ```
2. after that navigate the page like this:

   ```
    $.ajax(optionsFromWithin).done(function (data) {
    /*pass the data to next page for re use or save somewhere*/
       window.location.href = "/Controller/Action"; 
     });
   ```